# Add elements in struct after declare it

Tags: c

Why this don't work? In case I want add new elements in the struct, and reuse A

```
typedef struct People {
    int number;
    char name[30];
} people;

people A;
A = {12346,"name"};
```

---

I know the right way is to declare everything in one line.

```
TYPE_STRUCT VARIABLE_NAME = {DATA1,DATA2,...,DATA_N(elements of respective struct)}
```

Or add each DATA in one line.

```
A.number = 4321;
strcpy(A.name,"My name");
```

Comment: `A = (people){12346,"name"};` should work.

Comment: @usr I use the search 3 times, and google it, but can't find. I use expression "add elements" instead "initializing struct...", sorry about duplicate. my bad

Comment: "I know the right way is to declare everything in one line." - that's not (just) a declaration. And C does not care about lines (except for comments and preprocessor directives).